# How to get name of the day from date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `momentjs` and want to output the name of the day ie. "Wednesday" but the API only seems to offer a number.

Is there a way to do this without hard-coding it to a particular language?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [Format section of their documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

> **Day of Week** `dddd`    Sunday Monday ... Friday Saturday

```
moment().format('dddd');
```

Answer (score 3):

In case, if you want to get a name out of an index day

```
const day = 1; //second index after 0
moment().day(day).format("dddd") //Monday
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `moment().format('dddd');` to get full name of day like 'Sunday' , 'Monday'

use `moment().format('ddd');` to get three letter name like 'Sun' , 'Mon'

```js
let day_name_full = moment().format('dddd');
let day_name_three_letter = moment().format('ddd');

console.log('== To Get Day Name ==');
console.log("using format('dddd') =>",day_name_full);
console.log("using format('ddd') =>",day_name_three_letter);


console.log('== To Get Month Name ==');
let month_name_full = moment().format('MMMM');
let month_name_three_letter = moment().format('MMM');


console.log("using format('MMMM') =>",month_name_full);
console.log("using format('MMM') =>",month_name_three_letter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```